# Getting TableViewCell to Highlite When Finger Passes Over It

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is it possible to make a `UITableViewCell` high-lite when a finger passes over it? Not just when it pushes down on it, but when the finger is already sliding across the screen and runs over the tableviewcell? I've tried all of the gesture recognizers (including `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`) and haven't had any luck.

Comment: Gesture recognizer on the superview that detects what subviews are under the current location of the touch?

Comment: Have a look at responses to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286230/touches-began-in-uitableviewcontroller  (particularly last one)  might provide some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function, its similar to the one in the question mentioned in the comments:

(in your viewController)

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //assuming UITableView named tableView
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell;
    CGPoint touchedPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    for (int C = 0; C < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; C++) {
        //this should loop through all cells in your tableview

        tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:C]];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(tableViewCell.frame, touchedPoint)) {

            [tableViewCell setHighlighted:TRUE];
        }  
        else {
            [tableViewCell setHighlighted:FALSE];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[recognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

then...

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(id)sender
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    UIView *contentView = [recognizer view];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[contentView superview];
    [cell setSelected:YES];
}
```

I just tested this and it works exactly like what you are looking for.

EDIT: If I weren't in a rush, I would have done some introspection before type casting.